# IP Camera recorder class not working properly

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, webcam, mjpeg

Edit: I figured it out shortly after posting, it's amazing how asking a question can help you re-examine things :-). I commented the switch in the code.

I'm working on a class to download single frames from motion jpeg streams every so many seconds. It worked fine until I added some code to disconnect from the stream once a single jpeg is loaded. Now the "recorder" seems to be storing the first frame retrieved and not replacing the "image" with new content. I can destroy and recreate the object every time to fix this but that's not a very elegant solution. Any help would be appreciated!

Here's the code for the Recorder class:

```py
import cv2
import urllib2
import threading
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

class MJpegCam:

    def __init__(self, ip, timeout=5):
        self.ip = ip
        self.bytes= ''
        self.image = ''
        self.stream = None
        self.stopcam = False
        self.timeout = timeout

    def start(self):
        self.stream=urllib2.urlopen(self.ip, timeout=self.timeout)
        def run():
            while True:
                if self.stopcam:
                    self.stopcam = False
                    return
                try:
                    self.bytes+=self.stream.read(1024)
                    a = self.bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
                    b = self.bytes.find('\xff\xd9')
                    if a!=-1 and b!=-1:
                        jpg = self.bytes[a:b+2]
                        self.bytes= self.bytes[b+2:]
                        cv2img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8),cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
                        try:
                            cv2RGB = cv2.cvtColor(cv2img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                            self.image = Image.fromarray(cv2RGB)
                            self.stop() #This is where the program was breaking
                            return #
                        except Exception as e:
                            pass
                except AttributeError as e:
                    pass
        thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
        thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.stream.close()
        self.stopcam = False #this needed to be switched to False
        self.bytes = ''

    def getImage(self):
        return self.image
```

In the actual program I'm running multiple objects on separate processes but here's the basic idea:

```py
cam = MJpegCam(ip)
secs = 10

while(i < end):
  cam.start()
  time.sleep(cam.timeout)
  cam.stop()
  time.sleep(secs - cam.timeout)
```